# Append to list if specific word is entered

Tags: prolog, append

I am trying to append a list and a word together, and if the user types a specific word I want to add a certain letter to the list.

For example, I want to make the words entered in a list change based on the pronoun.

```
?- append([t,a,l,k], she, X).
X = [t, a, l, k, s].
```

so if the user enters [t, a, l, k] and she, Prolog will add 's' to the end of the list.

The code I have so far is only able to append the two entered values and not based on if the user enters a certain word.

```
append( [], X, X).                                   
append( [A | B], C, [A | D]) :- append( B, C, D).

result:
?- append([t,a,l,k], she, X).
X = [t, a, l, k|she].
```

How can I make it so if they type she prolog adds 's' to the list instead of 'she'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decompose the atom `she` into individual characters first.

It is also best to use `my_append/3` because `append/3` already exists.

```
my_append( [], W, [F]) :- atom_chars(W,[F|_]).
my_append( [A | B], W, [A | D]) :- my_append(B, W, D).

:- begin_tests(shemanator).

test("append 'she'", true(X == [t, a, l, k, s])) :-
   my_append([t,a,l,k], she, X).

test("append 'she' to an empty list", true(X == [s])) :-
   my_append([], she, X).

test("append 's'", true(X == [t, a, l, k, s])) :-
   my_append([t,a,l,k], s, X).
   
:- end_tests(shemanator).
```

And so

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: shemanator ... done
% All 3 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: Thank you but I honestly don't even understand why it works... I'm new to prolog and there's no mention of she or s in the my_append but it somehow knows to add change she to s.

Comment: @Pone Well, yes. Because one calls `my_append( [A | B], W, [A | D] )` with `W` bound to `she`, which results in a more calls to `my_append( [A | B], W, [A | D] )` with `W` always bound to `she` (along the recursion) which eventually results in a call to `my_append( [], W, [F])` with `W` still bound to `she`, which results in `she` being exploded into its characters through ` atom_chars(W,[F|_]).` which results in `F` being bound to the `s` in [`s`,`h`,`e`].

Comment: And then we are at the end because the query succeeds and the `[F] ` is actually the `D` of the caller, which is part of `[A|D]` up the call chain, and so we have the result. It's binding of variables and setting up of trees-with-values-at-leaves (i.e. terms) (but not evaluating) all the way down.